# Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert objects::Player@a1a4101 to flash.display.MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3

I recently started programming games with action script 3 for a school project. Now after watching some tutorials I wanted to combine the script with eachother to get the game I want.

The problem that now occurs is that a movieclip need to be converted, but flash is unable to. Why it has to be converted: I don't have a clue. As I said before, I am an absolute beginner.

I've searched the web and this website as well but nothing seems to be the same so I don't know how to solve it.

Flash Builder gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert objects::Player@a1d2101 to flash.display.MovieClip.
at screens::inGame/checkStuff()[C:\Users\Henk-Jan\Dropbox\Project P2 CMD 1\4. Multimedia production\Tutorials\StarlingProject\src\screens\inGame.as:294]
```

inGame.as Line 294:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < blocks.length; i++)
        {
            blocks[i].checkObj(char, i); //LINE 294*************************
            for(var s:int = 0; s < enemies.length; s++)
                blocks[i].checkObj(enemies[s], i);
        }
```

checkObj function in Block.as:

```
public function checkObj(obj:MovieClip, place:int):void{
        if(obj.x + obj.width / 2 > x - width / 2 && obj.x < x - width / 2 + 7 && Math.abs(obj.y - y) < height /2){
            obj.x = x - width / 2 - obj.width / 2; 
        }
        if(obj.x - obj.width / 2 < x + width / 2 && obj.x > x + width / 2 - 7 && Math.abs(obj.y - y) < height /2){
            obj.x = x + width / 2 + obj.width / 2; 
        }
        if(Math.abs(obj.x - x) < width / 2 + obj.width / 2 && obj.y < y - height / 2 && obj.floor > y - height / 2 && obj.onBlock != place){
            obj.floor = y - height / 2; 
            obj.onBlock = place;
        }
        if(Math.abs(obj.x - x) >= width / 2 + obj.width / 2 && obj.onBlock == place){
            obj.onBlock = -1;
            obj.floor = 600;
        }
        if(obj.y - obj.height / 2 < y + height / 2 && obj.y > y && Math.abs(obj.x - x) < width / 2 + obj.width / 2){
            obj.y = y + height / 2 + obj.height / 2;
        }
```

so, this is build in a Starling framework. The above code i part of a larger code that I won't post here, as you guys probably won't like that. var blocks is an Array that has the blocks in it where the char stands on ingame.

For the guys who are willing to import the whole code to flash builder > http://www75.zippyshare.com/v/37202056/file.html

I hope my problem can be solved very quickly, as my deadline is next week already...

best regards,

Henk-Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that you need to convert a movieclip, the problem is that you're trying to coerce a `Player` class into a `MovieClip` class (which it isn't).  `checkObj()` has a first argument of `obj:MovieClip`.  This is the issue.  Either change it to `obj:Player` or generalize it with a wildcard `obj:*`.

Comment: Do everyone a favor though, and don't use wildcards.

Comment: Thanks! The wildcard works.

Multiple objects are going through this function, so what would you suggest LDMS? When I set "Player" instead of * it fixes the player error, but the "enemy" objects use that function as well.

Comment: I'm assuming your Player and Enemy classes are extended from Sprite?  If so, (IIRC) you should be able to use `obj:Sprite` and it should work, since both Player and Enemy are derivatives.  Just be aware, referencing class specific properties of your subclasses won't work unless you resolve `myPlayer:Player = obj as Player` or `myEnemy:Enemy = obj as Enemy`